# Securing web services by authentication

Tags: php, android, rest, restful-authentication

I have just started working on my new project. It will be an android application which will interact with PHP web services running on a remote server. All the real work will be done by these web sevices. The android app will only connect to these using RESTful API.
The application will provide facilities to register as a new user or to log in. I want some of the sections of the app accessible to a user only if he is logged in. In this case, the corresponding web service should be executed only if the user is logged in. I want to know how can i achieve this. How can i deny access to a web services if a user is not logged in?

P.S. I am not looking for the exact code. Only rough idea of what should i do will be enough for me.

Comment: Use JWT (JSON Web Token).

Comment: Use session variable in PHP to hold the login status. The Android client will read the PHP session id from the cookie after login and then use this cookie to communicate with the server.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thank you. Fell in love with the JWT approch as i researched on it!